# Change the default spawn size of objects

Tags: modeling

When I add a cube to my file I would like it to spawn as 20x20cm instead of the default 2x2m.

In the scene tab I can achieve this by changing the unit scale to 0.1 and length to centimeters. When I now add a new cube to the scene it spawns as 20x20cm (see photo).

So everything is perfect I think but if I now save this startup file and exit the file and open a new one and create a cube it spawns as 200cm.

Does anyone know how to fix this so with every new file I open the default spawn size is 20cm?

[image]

Comment: "it spawns as 20x20cm (see photo)."> You probably added a cube before and changed its size via the Last Operator menu. This setting is kept during the session, but not into the save.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. Would there be any way to achieve what I describe in the question? I work in a very small scale so it is very annoying to have to scale down a cube every time I add one.